# Problem to find the objective function in this problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, binary-programming

I have the next real problem. I have a set of workers $W = \{w_1,\dots,w_{12}\}$ and I have to find the optimal distribution minimizing the jumps of the workers from one jobsite to another jobsite in 8 jobsites $S = \{S_1,\dots,S_8\}$, having the next matrix (cost matrix) that represent the telework for each worker:

\begin{bmatrix}MON & TUE & WEN & THU & FRI \\1&0&0&1&1& w_1\\1&1&0&0&1& w_2\\0&0&0&0&0& w_3\\0&1&1&1&0& w_4\\0&1&1&1&0& w_5\\1&1&1&0&0& w_6\\1&1&1&0&1& w_7\\1&1&1&0&1& w_8\\0&0&1&1&1& w_9\\1&0&1&1&1& w_{10}\\1&0&1&0&1& w_{11}\\1&0&0&1&1& w_{12}\\\end{bmatrix}

Where 1 represets a day in the office and 0 a day working at home. $w_3$ has all days with weigth 0 cause he cannot move from his jobsite, so I thought that it not make any cost, cause he cant jump, but he has to telework  MON and FRI.

Pls help me with that, i would be very greatful. Thaks!!

Comment: Do you know the requirements for each day ? for example on MON you need 3 workers, on TUE 5, etc

Comment: the workers that will be in the office each day is represented in the matrix MON will be 8 workers (8 ones) TUE six (6 ones) etc... I have to find the way that each worker change his jobsite the LESS as possible. Thaks for your question! ^^

Comment: Your problem is not well defined. Can you give an example of a complete (non optimal) solution of the problem ?

Comment: MON: w_2, w_1, w_7, w_5, w_4, w_{11}, w_{10}, w_{12}

Comment: MON: w_2(S_1), w_1(S_2), w_7(S_3), w_5(S_4), w_4(S_5), w_{10}(S_6), w_{11}(S_7), w_{12}(S_8),                                                                                TUE: w_2(S_1), w_8(S_2), w_3(S_3), w_9(S_4), w_4(S_5), w_{10}(S_6), w_{11}(S_7), w_{12}(S_8),                                                                                                    WEN: w_6(S_1), w_{10}(S_2), w_3(S_3), w_9(S_4),w_{12}(S_5),w_{11}(S_6), w_8(S_7), w_5(S_8),

Comment: THU: w_6(S_1), w_1(S_2), w_3(S_3), w_5(S_4), w_9(S_6), w_8(S_7), w_7(S_8),                                                                                                        FRI: w_2(S_1), w_1(S_2), w_6(S_3), w_5(S_4), w_4(S_5), w_{10}(S_6), w_{11}(S_7), w_7(S_8).

Comment: For examplo w_1 is always in S_2 soy it is nice! no cost. But w_5 chage S_4 for S_8 WEN soy it will be a cost (value as one cause it is one change)

Comment: I have to find the less change of jobsite as possible

Comment: Please define $S_i$ in the question. This needs to be clear if you want a helpful answer.

Comment: Done! thanks Kuifje!

Answer (score 2):

For each worker $i$ and each pair of consecutive office workdays $(j,k)$ for that worker, introduce a binary decision variable $x_{i,j,k}$ to indicate whether a change occurs.  The objective is to minimize $\sum_{i,j,k} x_{i,j,k}$, and you can enforce the desired behavior with linear constraints $$w_{i,j,s}-w_{i,k,t}\le x_{i,j,k},$$ where $s$ and $t$ are different job sites.  The idea is that if worker $i$ on day $j$ works at site $s$ and then on day $k$ works at site $t\not= s$, the left hand side is $1-0=1$, which forces $x_{i,j,k}=1$.

Comment: Thank you Rob, I'm going to work on that and I'll tell you if i have any problem! ^^

Comment: GM Rob, I'm doing a little example with 3 workers (w1,w2,w3) that works FRI, SAT and SUN in 2 job sites S1 and S2. w1 work at home on FRI, w2 on SAT and w3 on SUN ([[0,1,1], [1,0,1],[1,1,0]]) but i cant deduce the constraints that you are saying to me in your solution. Can you give an example?^^ THX!!

Comment: For worker $i=2$, there is only one pair $(j,k)=(\text{FRI},\text{SUN})$, and the constraints are \begin{align}w_{2,\text{FRI},\text{S1}}-w_{2,\text{SUN},\text{S2}}&\le x_{2,\text{FRI},\text{SUN}}\\ w_{2,\text{FRI},\text{S2}}-w_{2,\text{SUN},\text{S1}}&\le x_{2,\text{FRI},\text{SUN}}\end{align}